# Generate a set of unique elements in range

Tags: c++, vector

To start I am just learning C++.

I am trying to create a vector of four different ints ranging from 0:9. I am using a seed and randint() function to get different random numbers each time the program is ran. The problem I have is after receiving the random number how do I confirm that value isn't already held in the vector. Example of my code.

```
int seed()
{
    // Produce computers numbers
    int seed;
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter any Integer!\n";
    cin >> x;
    seed = randint(x) % 10;
    return seed;
}

int main ()
{
    while(keys.size() !=4)
    {
        key = seed();
    }
}
```

As you can see int key now holds the random number but I don't want to use keys.push_back(key) until I confirm that key is unique from any other number currently held in the vector.

Comment: Why not make an vector that has 0-9 in it, shuffle it and then grab the first 4 elements?

Comment: You probably want [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Look at what [algortihms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) are available and what [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has to offer.

Comment: Honestly, because I haven't learned how to shuffle a vector. This is an exercise from a book I'm reading and they want you to use randint(). Also I will need to know how because the other part of the program is supposed to have the user enter their own four numbers to try to guess my four numbers. On top of that they have to guess the numbers in the correct order as well. So I'm going to need to be able to test again like this throughout the program. Im stumped right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a shuffle algorithm of [Fisher-Yets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

You create an array of elements `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`
. Then walk through each element swapping it with a random index in range

```
std::vector<int> GenerateRandomUniqueNumbers(int len)
{
    if(len > 10) // Early exit
        return std::vector<int>();

    std::vector<int> range(10);
    std::iota(range.begin(), range.end(), 0); 
    // or just
    // std::vector<int> range = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
    {
        int j = random() % range.size();
        std::swap(range[i], range[j]);
    }
    range.resize(len);
    return range;
}
```

And then get first four elements of your array `Range`.

You can limit for loop to only four iterations.

Comment: Or just use std::shuffle

Comment: I've added limit to the loop so it can be stopped earlier than reaches the end of vector.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Answer (score 8):

How about using [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to store the numbers? Add to it as long as the size is less than four (in e.g. a loop).

If you need it in a vector then you can create the vector after generating the numbers in the set.

Comment: I am sure you guys are both correct, std:: hasn't been taught yet, so I will have to do some research on that. I'm sure they wanted me to use what has been covered thus far, but that gives me another way that I can research which is never bad. Thanks guys!

Comment: @B.Sabres15 Well if you're using a vector, then thats [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Most of the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) have a similar interface (set if member functions), so if you can use one then learning another is not so much work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lower_bound` to find the right insertion point to keep your vector in order.  Then you can use `binary_search` to tell if any element is in the vector before you do the insert.